# Debugging IPv6 connectivity in fresh Debian 12 installation

Tags: debian, routing, ipv6, ping, gateway

#### Context

I installed Debian 12 in my machine a couple of days ago, and since then I have been facing some issues with (outbound) IPv6 networking. From my investigation so far (having gone through infinitely many related posts on this and other Linux forums, none of which have been particularly helpful), it seems to me the default gateway for IPv6 is misconfigured, but I'm currently at my wit's end on how to proceed from here.

#### Reproducing the issue

A simple ping suffices to illustrate it:

```bash
$ ping -6 example.org                                                                                                                                                                                           
PING example.org(2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946 (2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946)) 56 data bytes                                                                                                            
^C                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
--- example.org ping statistics ---                                                                                                                                                                                
18 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 17394ms
```

whereas it works with *regular* IPv4:

```bash
$ ping -4 example.org                                                                                                                                                                                           
PING  (93.184.216.34) 56(84) bytes of data.                                                                                                                                                                        
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=116 ms                                                                                                                                         
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=194 ms                                                                                                                                         
^C                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
---  ping statistics ---                                                                                                                                                                                           
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms                                                                                                                                                     
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 116.459/155.372/194.285/38.913 ms
```

The issue is not limited to ICMP packets, `wget` and `curl` also fail to establish connection if targeting an IPv6 address. This also shows DNS is not the problem here, since the IPv6 address is succesfully resolved.

#### Setup

As mentioned, my setup is a recent installation of Debian 12 with GNOME. This means networking is handled by Network Manager, where the IPv6 method is set to `auto` and `ip6-privacy` is enabled (I already tried disabling it to no avail).

Output from relevant commands:

```bash
$ sudo dmesg | grep IPv6                                      
[10528.771325] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[10559.614635] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[18402.308519] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[18406.196405] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[18444.190916] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

So it looks like IPv6 is enabled at the kernel level (?).

```bash
$ ip -6 route                                                 
2a00:d100:18e2:9f00::/64 dev wlp2s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::1 dev wlp2s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
```

From what I can tell, `fe80::` is meant for [local networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6) so it should not be where requests are routed to by default. On the other hand, `2a00:d100:18e2:9f00::/56`  is the value my router claims for *prefix delegation*, but I am not entirely sure what that means. I tried to set it as the default gateway (with `sudo route add -A inet6 default gw 2a00:d100:18e2:9f00::`), but that didn't do the trick either.

```bash
$ sudo route -A inet6                                                                                                                                                                                       
Kernel IPv6 routing table                                                                                
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref  Use If                                                                                                                                     
2a00:d100:18e2:9f00::/64       [::]                       U    600 1      0 wlp2s0                                                                                                                                 
fe80::/64                      [::]                       U    1024 1      0 wlp2s0                                                                                                                                
[::]/0                         _gateway                   UG   600 5      0 wlp2s0                                                                                                                                 
localhost/128                  [::]                       Un   0   7      0 lo                                                                                                                                     
zenbook/128                    [::]                       Un   0   3      0 wlp2s0                                                                                                                                 
zenbook/128                    [::]                       Un   0   2      0 wlp2s0                                                                                                                                 
zenbook/128                    [::]                       Un   0   3      0 wlp2s0                                                                                                                                 
ff00::/8                       [::]                       U    256 6      0 wlp2s0                                                                                                                                 
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1      0 lo
```

```bash
$ traceroute -6 google.com
traceroute to google.com (2a00:1450:4003:80f::200e), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets                                                                                                                                  
 1  * * *                                                                                                
 2  * * *                                                                                                
 3  * * *                                                                                                
[continues ...]
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

If any other command output is required in order to make progress, please let me know in the comments. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: do you have enabled dhcpv6 on your router?

Comment: Ipv6 doesn't require your router to have an up address on your subnet. I'm not 100% convinced IPv4s ever did either (I saw cases where it didn't). So `fe80::1` might possibly be right. You might want to try enabling "stateful addressing" on the router which sets up a dhcp6 server. This isn't enabled by default on all routers.

Comment: Also you could look for your routers ipv6 address if it has one. This should start with `2a00:d100:18e2:9f00:` although the last two 0s could conceivably be different.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. @D'ArcyNader How could I tell if DHCPv6 is enabled on my router? Can I infer it from a command run on my machine? The router is a GRG-4280us from Comtrend, but I couldn't find much documentation online. There is just one reference to IPv6 (in the main menu) that pretty much just gives that IPv6 address I thought could be the gateway, and the DHCP section does not mention IPv6 (or DHCPv6) at all. Does that mean it is not _compatible_ with IPv6 in some sense?

Comment: @PhilipCouling similar to my previous comment, I could not find a setting for that in my router admin page either, nor a corresponding IPv6 address for it. To be clear, I am asking this question because I started facing these issues in my new setup, whereas I never encountered them previously on my Mac, so I assumed the problem was on my new machine's networking. Could it be that I should just not be using IPv6 at all and need to somehow disable it on my machine?

Comment: Sorry folks, just noticed in the main menu there's an address for the _IPv6 Default Gateway_ with the value `fe80::200:5eff:fe00:1f4`. However, if I try to ping it I get `Destination unreachable: Address unreachable`.

Comment: Further update, I discovered a ping6 testing capability within the diagnostics tab of the router. Pings for IPv4 work as expected, but all packets are lost for the IPv6 version (DNS still works fine here). Given I never experienced this issue before even though the router is the exact same, I'm starting to think I should just disable IPv6 traffic on my laptop, as I don't have any particular interest on it.

Comment: It's completely normal to have a link local address as gateway. Eg: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861 "The use of link-local addresses to uniquely identify routers (for  Router Advertisement and Redirect messages) makes it possible for  hosts to maintain the router associations in the event of the site  renumbering to use new global prefixes.". Mentioning an advantage means it's intended (and also it probably avoids an additional resolution). Also @D'ArcyNader DHCPv6 is often not needed: router advertisements are often enough. I'm using IPv6 without DHCPv6 right now.

Comment: Also a link-local address is complete only with its associated interface. So: `fe80::1`: invalid address. `fe80::1%wlp2s0`: valid address. Even with ping (but using `-I wlp2s0` instead in ping gets the same effect).

Comment: But then I didn't read correctly OP wrote /56 in such case yes DHCPv6 might be needed between ISP and router ( just as @D'ArcyNader suggested I guess) and I don't know much about this part. How it would choose to provide specifically the first /64 to the LAN, I have no idea either.

Comment: Probably also good to check another device other to see what's happening. It's a good idea to rule out Linux first because frankly it should just work these days. Have you tried your mobile phone? Google for "what is my ip" to see if that uses IPv6.